# How does delay function work?

Tags: c++, c, windows, delay

Delay function under dos.h in C/C++.

I was trying to make delay function by giving compiler many calculations to do and calibrated 
it to delay for 1 second but when I executed the same on another PC(s) , it showed me different result(s) .

When compiler encounters `delay() ;` statement in program ; what does it do ,  how delay function work so accurately  . What goes on in the background .

[Answer need not be very technical .]

Comment: Just out curiosity, where are you using `dos.h`?

Comment: To create typing effect while printing a string & also while using sound() function in piano program .

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation tells you all you need to know.](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_128.html)

Much like `sleep`, `nanosleep` and `usleep`, this function instructs the Operating System to yield the CPU time to other processes.

Answer (score 1):

Computers typically have timer hardware and operating systems typically offer a way for a process to yield the CPU for a specified amount time. A quality implementation of `delay()` would typically make use of these services.

A calibrated busy loop -- as described in your question -- is wasteful and is therefore rarely done (perhaps except on embedded platforms).

Comment: You might as well have said it works on electricity.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The C and C++ standards do not require that the code be run using electricity. :)

Comment: @Mysticial: dos.h is not defined by C or C++ ;)